# Inline flex added for input boxes not responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been trying to a series of input boxes to be inline but also to be responsive such that it does not get overlapped on the row below.

When shrinking the contents gets overlayed on top of div directly below and not sure how to fix this

```css
/** Editable **/

.container {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}


/** Not editable onwards **/

.multiple-choice--small {
  height: 24px;
  padding: 2px 10px 0 36px;
}

.full {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.quarter,
.one-quarter {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.third,
.one-third {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33333%;
}

.form-group {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.form-date .form-group {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  clear: none;
}

.form-date .form-group label {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.form-date .form-group input {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.form-date .form-group-year {
  width: 70px;
}

.form-group-error {
  margin-right: 15px;
  border-left: 4px solid #b10e1e;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 641px) {
  .form-group-error {
    border-left: 5px solid #b10e1e;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
}

.form-control-error {
  border: 4px solid #b10e1e;
}

.error-message {
  font-family: "nta", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.25;
  color: #b10e1e;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full" style="padding-top:10px;">
    <div class="one-quarter"><span style="font-weight:bold">&nbsp;t&nbsp;</span></div>
    <div class="one-third">
      <span class="multiple-choice--small" style="display: inline-flex;  padding: 0;">
              <input type="radio" style="min-width:24px; min-height:24px">
              <label>&nbsp;Input A&nbsp;</label>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="form-date" >
                          <div class="form-group day" style="margin:0px">
                              <input style="width:40px" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group month" style="margin:0px">
                              <input style="width:40px"  class="form-control" >
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group year" style="margin:0px">
                              <input style="width:50px"  class="form-control" >
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
          </span>
    </div>
    <div class="one-third">
      <span class="multiple-choice--small" style="display: inline-flex;  padding: 0;">
              <input type="radio"  style="min-width:24px; min-height:24px">
              <div>&nbsp;Input B&nbsp;</div>
              <div  class="form-group" >
                  <div class="form-date" style="background: blue;">
                      <div class="form-group day" style="margin:0px">
                          <input style="width:40px" class="form-control" >
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group month" style="margin:0px">
                          <input style="width:40px"  class="form-control" >
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group year" style="margin:0px">
                          <input style="width:50px"  class="form-control">
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="full">
    <div class="one-quarter">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="one-third">
      <span class="multiple-choice--small" style="display: inline-flex; padding: 0;">
                  <input type="radio" style="min-width:24px; min-height:24px" checked>
              <div>&nbsp; Radio A</div>
              </span>
      <span class="error-message" style="display:none;"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="one-third">
      <span class="multiple-choice--small" style="display: inline-flex;  padding: 0;">
             <input  type="radio" style="min-width:24px; min-height:24px" checked>
             <div>&nbsp; Radio B</div>
          </span>
      <span class="error-message" style="display:none;"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Full screen:
[image]

Responsive:

[image]

Edit: Added JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ducking/0n8cdvtx/13/

Comment: _"it seems JSfiddle is not responding to inline-flex"_ - no idea what you mean by that. JSFiddle is simply a platform to test HTML & CSS (& JS) directly in your browser. `inline-flex` works in there, the same way it does elsewhere.

Comment: It oddly doesn't recognize inline flex in my code; just adding updating my post with it attached since stackoverflows implementation is a bit ugly to my liking but that isn't really my question tbh

Comment: Both in the snippet here and in your fiddle, inspecting these elements that you put `display:inline-flex` on via inline styles, shows that they _have_ that display value, exactly as one would expect based on the code.

Comment: Apologies i found my missing css in another file; fixed it and now acts the same @CBroe

Answer (score 1):

Use the flex property on the dates class.

Comment: Hey welcome to stackoverflow! This nearly works but still gets overlayed for mobile devices (roughly at 642px - large mobile device).. please see the fiddle

Comment: you can use "display: flex; flex-direction: column;" with media query on class with name full.

Comment: Would there be anyway of just getting the last input box to go below the input boxes? It's only between 600-700px where this issue happens, and if I create a media query this will create a mobile layout which the rest of the page doesn't respond mobile layout

Comment: set min-width: 125px; for form-group class. I think that will help you.

Comment: I can’t accept this as an answer till it’s fixable tbh; this problem can be recreated in a jfiddle and didn’t really come and to ask a question and receive investigation answers